# Complex integral by definition

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Can anyone see a way to do the integral under the curve $\gamma(t)=2e^{it}, t\in[0, 2\pi]$:

$$\int _\gamma \frac{2z}{z^2-2}dz$$

My intention is to use the definition (This exercise appears right after the definition of complex integral). After some accounts I arrived at:

$$\int _\gamma \frac{2z}{z^2-2}dz= \int_o^{2\pi}\frac{i(cos(2t)+isen(2t))}{2(cos(2t)+isen(2t))+1}dt=0+4i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2+cos(2t)}{5+4cos(2t)}dt$$

But calculating this last integral is being very difficult. Does anyone see an easier way to solve this?

Comment: In view of the placement of the exercise, and your comment on the answer given, I don't think this really answers your question, but one can evaluate the integral using only winding numbers, either by splitting the integrand into partial fractions, or by expressing it as $f'(z)/(f(z) - 2)$ where $f(z) = z^2$, so the integral is transformed into $2\pi i$ times the winding number of $f \circ \gamma$ around $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you have two singularities
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{2z}{z^2 -2}dz = \int_\gamma \frac{2z}{(z+\sqrt{2})(z-\sqrt{2})} dz
$$
You can make an argument using symmetry or calculating by using the Residue theorem.
That is,
$$
\lim\limits_{z\to \pm \sqrt{2}} \frac{2z}{z \pm \sqrt{2}} = \pm 1
$$

Comment: This reasoning is very good, but exercise before of Residue theorem. In fact, we only have the definition and analogous to the fundamental calculus theorem. I think exercise is in the wrong place.